# results with between and count in a select

Tags: mysql

How can I make a list where I need the orders to be between the date '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/01', but also only show the customers with more than one order?
I have these orders, but they only work for me separately.

NEW: "The big problem I have is that there are cliente that are repeated in the pedido, but one has the date within the range and the other does not, so you need to filter having a repeated cliente but with at least one pedido within the date 'fecha_ped'."

ejecution:

```
SELECT  cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli
group by (pedido.num_ped) 
having pedido.fecha_ped between '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/15'  ;
```

this return:

```
    104 Úrsula  Delta Camacho   2018-10-05
    102 María   Sánchez Cid 2018-10-05
    106 Pedro   Jiménez Ruiz    2018-10-05
    105 Carmen  Hernández Pío   2018-10-05
    107 Raúl    Rodrigo Roca    2018-10-05
```

ejecution2:

```
SELECT  cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM repartocomidas_tarea5.cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli 
group by (pedido.cliente ) 
having count(pedido.cliente)>=2  ;
```

this return:

```
    101 Luis    Ramírez Pardo   2018-09-21
    102 María   Sánchez Cid 2018-09-21
    105 Carmen  Hernández Pío   2018-09-21
    104 Úrsula  Delta Camacho   2018-09-22
    107 Raúl    Rodrigo Roca    2018-09-22
```

the table pedido contains these columns:
num_ped,fecha_ped, hora_servir,hora_ped,hora_entrega,cliente

the table cliente contains these columns:
    num_cli,nombre,apellidos,domicilio,cod_postal,localidad,telefono,tipo_cli,bono_canjebale.

the values of pedido:

```
100101  2018-09-21  10:00:00    14:30:00    14:35:00        101
100107  2018-09-22  10:55:00    14:30:00    null            101
100102  2018-09-21  10:15:00    14:00:00    13:58:00        102
100110  2018-10-05  10:05:00    14:00:00    14:05:00        102
100103  2018-09-21  10:30:00    15:00:00    null            103
100106  2018-09-22  11:08:00    14:15:00    14:20:00        104
100109  2018-10-05  11:56:00    14:45:00    14:48:00        104
100104  2018-09-21  10:44:00    14:30:00    14:40:00        105
100112  2018-10-05  12:25:00    14:15:00    14:20:00        105
100111  2018-10-05  11:34:00    14:30:00    14:38:00        106
100108  2018-09-22  11:56:00    13:45:00    14:01:00        107
100113  2018-10-05  09:45:00    13:45:00    13:56:00        107
100105  2018-09-21  10:56:00    14:00:00    14:08:00        108
```

values of cliente:

```
101 Luis    Ramírez Pardo
102 María   Sánchez Cid
103 Martín  Guerrero López
104 Úrsula  Delta Camacho
105 Carmen  Hernández Pío
106 Pedro   Jiménez Ruiz
107 Raúl    Rodrigo Roca
108 Soledad Campillo Molina
109 Lucía   Gómez Prados
```

Comment: `but they only work for me separately` ... you are lucky that either of these queries even _run_ on MySQL, or any other database, because they are logically invalid.  You can't/shouldn't select columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause of an aggregation query.  Please add sample data and expected output to make this a complete question.

Comment: have you triend to use UNION ALL? see my answer below

Comment: Your `fecha_ped` datatype is TIME ....

Comment: Sorry, I entered the date_ped in the wrong order. It is already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To combine results use UNION ALL. But make sure they have the same column to select

```
SELECT  cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli
group by (pedido.num_ped) 
having pedido.fecha_ped between '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/15'  
UNION ALL
SELECT  cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM repartocomidas_tarea5.cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli 
group by (pedido.cliente ) 
having count(pedido.cliente)>=2  ;
```

But if you want for the result to meet both condition try this.

```
SELECT  cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM repartocomidas_tarea5.cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli 
group by (pedido.cliente,pedido.num_ped ) 
having count(pedido.cliente)>=2 AND (pedido.fecha_ped between '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/15');
```

but if you want just either of the condition change your having to `OR` like this

```
having count(pedido.cliente)>=2 OR (pedido.fecha_ped between '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/15');
```

Comment: The `;` before `UNION ALL` will make sure that this query return result from the first query only and the second query will give `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL` message.

Comment: It's fine if I delete ";".
But what I need is for the result to meet both conditions at the same time, if a condition is not met in the list.

Comment: do you want to meet both condition or atleast one of the condition?

Comment: Those that meet the conditions must appear at the same time.

Comment: In the second option I have this error: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Try to add pedido.cliente in your select

Comment: The "group by (pedido.cliente,pedido.num_ped ) " fail.

Comment: you must not forget you select `pedido.cliente,pedido.num_ped`. this is requirement for group by

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```html
SELECT DISTINCT(p.cliente),c.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped
FROM pedido AS p 
LEFT JOIN cliente AS c ON p.cliente=c.num_cli
WHERE p.fecha_ped >= DATE_FORMAT('YYYY/MM/DD','2018/10/01') AND p.fecha_ped <= DATE_FORMAT('YYYY/MM/DD','2018/10/15') HAVING COUNT(p.cliente)>=2;
```

Comment: Sorry but in which MySQL version does `HAVING` function is before `GROUP`? I'm a bit outdated because I mainly still use MySQL 4.1 (as 90% of our client still use it)

Comment: I check this with: 
group by (pedido.cliente)
but don´t show any result.

Comment: No, I have syntax error in the original answer. I use the where part for test, but this not show results.

Comment: @Kishan I add 
"group by p.num_ped HAVING COUNT(p.cliente)>=2;" but this not show nothing. Your code need "group by" for use "having"

Comment: Just remove group by as we have added DISTINCT and check it.

Comment: Just changed query please check I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

May I add another suggestion.

```
SELECT cliente.num_cli, nombre, apellidos, min(fecha_ped),max(fecha_ped),count(*) 
FROM cliente JOIN pedido
ON cliente.num_cli=pedido.cliente
WHERE pedido.fecha_ped between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-15'
GROUP BY pedido.cliente
having COUNT(*) >=2 ;
```

**Edit:**
After looking at your data (and creating a fake test data on my side), I've come up with this query below:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS "Total Orders" 
FROM cliente a LEFT JOIN pedido b ON a.num_cli=b.cliente 
WHERE b.fecha_ped BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15' GROUP BY num_cli;
```

The `COUNT(*) AS "Total Orders"` will show how many orders `GROUP BY num_cli` between the date you requested. This will show all results.

By adding `HAVING COUNT(*) >=2;` like query below, will only show cliente that have ordered more than once:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS "Total Orders" 
FROM cliente a LEFT JOIN pedido b ON a.num_cli=b.cliente 
WHERE b.fecha_ped BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15' GROUP BY num_cli 
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2;
```

*I edited the `b.hora_servir` to `b.fecha_ped`

**Edit 2:**

Ok, I'm just trying something here. Tell me if this is at least close to what you try to achieve.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT num_cli,nombre,apellidos,TotalOrders,IF(mdate BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15',CONCAT("Last Purchase date on ",mdate),"None") AS "Checking" FROM
(SELECT num_cli,nombre,apellidos,MAX(fecha_ped) mDate,COUNT(*) AS "TotalOrders" 
FROM cliente a LEFT JOIN pedido b ON a.num_cli=b.cliente 
WHERE b.fecha_ped BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15' GROUP BY num_cli 
UNION
SELECT num_cli,nombre,apellidos,MAX(fecha_ped) mDate,COUNT(*) AS "TotalOrders" 
FROM cliente a LEFT JOIN pedido b ON a.num_cli=b.cliente 
WHERE b.fecha_ped NOT BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15' GROUP BY num_cli 
ORDER BY num_cli) a) b WHERE (TotalOrders=2 OR checking <> "None");
```

Comment: 0 rows. The big problem is the pedido.fecha_ped with 1 date into the condition and other date out of condition. cliente have 2 pedido but 1 in the conditional date 'fecha_pedido'.

Comment: I see. Could you please update your question with how the `cliente` and `pedido` data looks like inside the table? And makeup an example of your desired output? That would be most helpful to get further.

Comment: Updated with cliente and pedido info. :)

Comment: I change b.hora_servir to b.fecha_ped, but this show in total orders result 1

Comment: the result of second code is 1 row by "cliente", and having count is not posible. If one "cliente" have 1 "pedido" into the date "fecha_ped" and 1 out of the date"fecha_ped", this not show the cliente with "having" use. The condition need separate count of pedido.cliente and if cliente have 1 pedido.fecha_ped into date, show this.

Comment: yes, from the data you've provided there are no occurrences where a customer has ordered more than once. Therefore, all customers "Total Order" result will be 1. I have tested with adding another row of data in `pedido` for cliente=104 with a different date "100113" "2018-10-09" "11:56:00" "14:45:00" "14:48:00" "104" and re-run the query, it will return "Total Orders" for cliente=104 is "2"

Comment: Do you want the "Total Orders" counted within the date range of `BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-15'` and another row where the "Total Orders" counted out of the date range given? So the result would be two rows for each customer whereby the "Total Orders" value is in and out of the date range, correct?

Comment: I have very hard teachers and that's why it's hard for me to know how to meet so much contradictory requirement of this exercise.

Comment: What I'm looking for are:" num_cli, nombre, apellidos" of cliente who have made 2 or more purchases "pedido", and who have made at least 1 purchase between the dates.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to update my query to follow your condition :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution using a condition to the result of the union of the tables.

```
SELECT  NUMERO , nombre, apellidos FROM
(
(SELECT  cliente.num_cli AS NUMERO, CLIENTE.num_cli AS NC, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped AS FECHA, num_ped, total_pedido as TOTAL
FROM cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli
group by (pedido.num_ped) 
having pedido.fecha_ped between '2018/10/01' and '2018/10/15') 

UNION

(SELECT  cliente.num_cli AS NUMERO,CLIENTE.num_cli AS NC, nombre, apellidos, fecha_ped AS FECHA, num_ped, COUNT(pedido.cliente) AS TOTAL
FROM repartocomidas_tarea5.cliente,pedido
where pedido.cliente=cliente.num_cli 
group by (pedido.cliente ) 
having (count(pedido.cliente)>=2) ) 


) 
AS RESULTADO 
WHERE NUMERO=NC
GROUP BY numero
having (count(nombre)>=2) order by NUMERO ;
;
```

RESULT:

```
 NUMERO nombre  apellidos
    102 María   Sánchez Cid
    104 Úrsula  Delta Camacho
    105 Carmen  Hernández Pío
    107 Raúl    Rodrigo Roca
```

Comment: after of second look, i change: "SELECT  NUMERO, nombre, apellidos FROM
(
(SELECT  cliente.num_cli AS NUMERO"     to    "SELECT  NC , nombre, apellidos FROM
(
(SELECT  pedido.cliente AS NUMERO"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating a new column with the numbers of `pedidos` of each client, so you can avoid this column to fix your problem.

Think that you are trying to insert the query values into a table that dont have the same numbers of columns.

Here you code fixed.

```
insert into cliente_vip (num_cli, nombre, apellidos)
select p.cliente, c.nombre, c.apellidos
from pedido p
inner join cliente c
    on c.num_cli = p.cliente
where p.fecha_ped between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-15'
group by p.cliente having count(p.cliente) >= 2;
```